# Chart does not render if call show() method of form

Tags: codenameone

I want to render chart and some table and textfield in a single screen. But when I show the form, chart comes and goes just like a flash screen and only  rest of ui shows up. In case if, I don't show the form only Chart renders but not any other components. Is there any way I can show Chart and other components on same screen at same time ? 
I am using CN1aChartEngine library to generate charts.
My code is :

---

```
// Inside current form
//some other components    
.
.
Context context = new Context();
ChartDemo demo = new ChartDemo();
Intent intent = demo.execute(context);
context.startActivity(intent);


//In start() method

current.show();
```

If I comment the above line only chart shows up otherwise only components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.startActivity()` shows a new form.  If you just want the view, you should use `ChartFactory.getXXXView()` instead of `ChartFactory.getXXXIntent()`.  That way you'll get a view whose peer is a CN1 Component that can be added into a hierarchy with other components.

See [this method](https://github.com/shannah/CN1aChartEngineDemo/blob/master/src/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/ChartsInBoxLayout.java#L79) for an example that returns a Component of a chart.  It makes use of `getXXXView()` and then `View.getPeer()` to retrieve the CN1 component.

I'm working on modifying the API to get rid of the android-stuff and make it a more natural fit for CN1 so hopefully it will be more intuitive in future releases.